# I need to capture the action status within apostrophe symbol using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to create custom property field as File Action was: and need to capture the file action result " was Created by" from below payload using regex. I have bit challenge to capture the "was created by" character from this payload using regex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Payload:

```
UTC msg='c:\program files\test\test.dll' was created by 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
```

Comment: What environment are you using the regex in (C#, F#, C++, bash, perl). There may be another solution that doesn't involve regex at all.

Comment: Hi msanford, its perl and also i found one more option to filter this:

Comment: UTC msg=.*["']\s(.*?)["']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will only match what's inside last apostrophes : `(?<=\s').*?(?='\.$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VcVzRa/1)

There are also other possibilities, for example :

this one, result is in Group 1 : `'.*?'.*?'(.*?)'.$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oo2OW9/1)

or this other one, result is also in Group 1 : `\s'(.*?)'.$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VcVzRa/2)

Comment: @karthick-g if you upvoted don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work